# ImageViews in circle

Tags: java, android

I want to put 20 ImageView objects in LinearLayout rotated so that they form a circle. Is this possible and how, and is this the right approach for creating circular layout of ImageView objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not conversant with the android API, but it doesn't look like you can *bend* a `LinearLayout` into a circle.  *Rotating* it should only change it's angle (horizontal versus vertical versus diagonal).

Probably, you're going to want to do something based off of an `AbsoluteLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, then perform geometry-related math to find out the positions the various elements need to be at.

Ideally, for future re-use, you should actually create a new `CircularLayout` that could be applied to containers.  You want the API to require a `List` of some sort of the elements (plus optionally padding), then have the layout perform the necessary math.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout can only present child elements either vertical or horizontal. You can position the ImageViews to form a circle if you use a RelativeLayout, but rotating them will include lots of calculations

Answer (score 0):

consider using the canvas and draw paint functions

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your XML

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/myImageontoolbar"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_width="10mm"
android:layout_height="10mm"
android:layout_gravity="left"
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
```

Your Gradle

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```